# Cakephp : Multi-Model Comment system

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I'm using cakephp, I have a model "comment" with two fields : "model_type" and "model_id" in order to comment every item of my application (eg Picture, News, Article, ...) with a single Comment model.

I wonder how to make this. (A component "Comment" for controller that could be commented ?)

Finally I want to list comment in view just with a helper: 
$comment->show('model_name', 'item_id');
that would display correctly paginated comments and a form for adding a new comment to the item.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: See this too : http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/AD7six/2008/03/13/polymorphic-behavior

## The Solution

A multi model commenting system and pagination just with :

```
<?php echo $this->element('comments', 
    array(
        'model_type' => "model_name", 
        'model_id' => $data['model']['id'],
        'order_field' => 'created',
        'order' => 'asc')); ?>
```

### The model

Scheme :

```
- id
- model_type
- model_id
- content
(optional:)
- user_id
- created
- updated
- rating
- ...
```

The Comment Model :

```
// {app}/models/comment.php
class Comment extends AppModel{
    public $name = 'Comment';
    
    // List of model that could be commented
    protected $model_list = array(
        'news' => array(
            'name' => 'News', // here it's the model's name
            'field' => 'validated'), // A field for validation ( allow comments only on validaded items)
        'articles' => array(
            'name' => 'Article',
            'field' => 'validated')
    );
    
        // This is an example
    public $belongsTo = array( 
        'User' => array(
            'conditions' => 'User.validated = true'
            )
        );
    
    public $validate = array(
        'model_type' => array(
            'rule' => 'checkModelType',
            'message' => "Something goes wrong !"
        ),
        'model_id' => array(
            'rule' => 'checkModelId',
            'message' => "Something goes wrong !"
        ),
        'content' => array(
             'rule' => 'notEmpty',        
             'message' => "Empty content !"
         )
    );
    
        // Check if the model is commentable
    public function checkModelType($data){
        $model_type = $data['model_type'];
        return in_array($model_type, array_keys($this->model_list));
    }
    
        // Check if the item exists and is validated
    public function checkModelId($data){
        $model_id = intval($data['model_id']);
        
        $model = $this->model_list[$this->data['Comment']['model_type']];
                
        $params = array(
            'fields' => array('id', $model['field']),
            'conditions' => array(
                $model['name'].'.'.$model['field'] => 1, // Validated item
                $model['name'].'.id' => $model_id
                )
        );
            
                // Binding model to Comment Model since there is no $belongsTo
        return (bool) ClassRegistry::init($model['name'])->find('first', $params);
    }
}
```

### The Controller

```
// {app}/controllers/comments_controller.php
class CommentsController extends AppController
{
    public $name = 'Comments';
    
        // Pagination works fine !
    public $paginate = array(
        'limit' => 15,
        'order' => array(            
            'Comment.created' => 'asc')    
        );
    
    // The action that lists comments for a specific item (plus pagination and order !)
    public function view($model_type, $model_id, $order_field = 'created', $order = 'DESC'){
        $conditions = array(
                'Comment.model_type' => $model_type, 
                'Comment.model_id' => $model_id
                );
        
                // (optional)
        if($order_field != 'created') {
            $this->paginate['order'] = array(
                'Comment.'.$order_field => $order,
                'Comment.created' => 'asc');
        }
        
                // Paginate comments
        $comments = $this->paginate($conditions);
                
                // This allow to use paginator with requestAction
        $paginator = ClassRegistry::getObject('view')->loaded['paginator'];
        $paginator->params = $this->params;
        return compact('comments', 'paginator');
    }

    public function add(){
        // What you want !
    }
}
```

### The views

#### Comments element

```
/* {app}/views/elements/comments.ctp
@params : $model_type
*   : $model_id
* 
* */

$result = $this->requestAction("/comments/view/$model_type/$model_id/$order_field/$order/", $this->passedArgs);
$paginator = $result['paginator'];
$comments = $result['comments'];

$paginator->options(array('url' => $this->passedArgs));
?>
<h2>Comments</h2>

<fieldset class="commentform">
<legend>Add un commentaire</legend>
<?php
    // Form
    echo $form->create('Comment', array('action' => 'add'));
    echo $form->hidden('model_type', array('value' => $model_type));
    echo $form->hidden('model_id', array('value' => $model_id));
    echo $form->input('content');
<?php
    echo $form->end('Send');
?>
</fieldset>
<div class="paginationBar">
    <?php
        echo $paginator->prev('<<  ', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled'));
        echo '<span class="pagination">',$paginator->numbers(),'</span>';
        echo $paginator->next('  >>', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled'));
    ?>
</div>
<?php
    foreach($comments as $comment){
        echo $this->element('comment', array('comment' => $comment));
    }
?>
<div class="paginationBar">
    <?php
        echo $paginator->prev('<<  ', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled'));
        echo '<span class="pagination">',$paginator->numbers(),'</span>';
        echo $paginator->next('  >>', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled'));
    ?>
    
    <p><br />
    <?php
        echo $paginator->counter(array('format' => 'Page %page% on %pages%, displayi  %current% items of %count%'));
    ?>
    </p>
</div>
```

#### Comment element

```
//{app}/views/elements/comment.ctp
// A single comment view
$id = $comment['Comment']['id'];
?>
<div class="comment">
<p class="com-author">
<span class="com-authorname"><?=$comment['User']['name']?>&nbsp;</span>
<span class="com-date">(<?=$comment['Comment']['created']?>)</span>
</p>
<p class="com-content"><?=$comment['Comment']['content']?></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

hm... it would be pretty complicated if you want to display paginated comments like that. You should use lazy loading: don't actually load the comments until the user click on it or something.

You should probably make an element. you can pass model_name and model_id to it. And in the element, you can create a comment 'widget' that can directly send the comment to your comments controller, using ajax; and load the paginated comments using ajax also.

Comment: I think an element will do, with the special function "requestAction" to load comments (for pagination I'm still looking)

Comment: you don't need requestAction if you use lazy loading (send an ajax request directly to your comments controller). That way the setup is simpler, and you don't break any conventions. http://book.cakephp.org/view/1234/AJAX-Pagination

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](http://cakedc.com/downloads/view/cakephp_comments_plugin) plugin (it's actually a component) developed by CakeDC.

You could either implement that or, use that to create your own solution.

Comment: The plugins seems very complicated, I'm pretty sure there is an easy way but thanks.

Comment: Which is why I also suggested using that to create your own solution, when you start looking at using `requestAction` there is usually a better way of designing the app